# How to remove tags from RichTextField and calculate words saved in RichTextField Django?

Tags: python, django

Below is my model
I want to calculate the word count in the RichTextField , I tried
`len(blog.content.split())`
but the problem with this is that it doesn't removes the tags and calculates them too, whereas I want only the word count and not tags like `<img>` , `<p>` etc.

```py
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(
        verbose_name="title",
        blank=True
    )
    tagline = models.TextField(
        verbose_name="tagline",
        blank=True
    )
    content = RichTextField(
        verbose_name="content",
        blank=True
    )
    image = models.TextField(
        verbose_name="image",
        blank=True
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove all the HTML Tags from blog.content and then count no of words. You can do this in two ways:

1. Extract text from HTML / blog.content using BeautifulSoup.

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(blog.content, 'html.parser')
    word_count = len(soup.get_text().split())
```

OR

2. Use regex for removing all the HTML Tags and then take word count.

   ```
    import re
    text = re.sub(r"]*>", " ", blog.content)
    word_count = len(text.split())
   ```